# Datetimepicker - converting to second units

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have been wracking my brain for days..

How do you take a datetimepicker box value and convert the 24hr time format HH:mm:ss to complete total unit seconds?

Basically if the datetimepicker is set to 01:01:01 The answer I am looking for would be 3661

Thank you for any help and reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Dim dt As DateTime = Now()
    Dim d2 As DateTime = Now.Date
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = dt.Subtract(d2)
    Dim s As String = ts.TotalSeconds
```

Get time by using Now for dt.
Get only the date for d2 which renders the time 00:00:00.
Subtract the lesser and voila :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it was simple but I just could not get it right. So simple I had to laugh at myself.

Comment: Ha! Thank you again, I been programming for about hmm 2 days now. I am pretty proud of myself with what I got so far considering I have no vb knowledge. You and the many others here have gave me a lot of knowledge just looking through it all. Thanks for being part of the group and being here for me.

Comment: I came across a new problem with this, If you use 2 date time pickers, if you set one to 01:00:00 and you set the other one to 00:30:00 the result is 01:30:00 instead of 00:30:00, any ideas how to fix that? The user cannot select the day, it is only strictly time in 24hr HH:mm:ss

Comment: Hmm thats not true for me. If I subtract one Datetimepicker value from the other I get the correct result. Dim i as Double = DTP1.Value.Subtract(DTP2.Value).TotalSeconds